# Explain concept of instantiating a model with another model as argument? VGGFace(model='resnet50', include_top=False)

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, resnet

I came across this line of code:

`VGGFace(model='resnet50', include_top=False)`

Could someone please explain to what this means? From my knowledge, VGGFace is a model trained to recognise faces, and then it accepts another model as an argument. So do we have two models? I am confused.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact it does recognizes faces, but the `model` parameter is used to specify which architecture is used, in this case `resnet50`, see: https://github.com/rcmalli/keras-vggface#available-models.

Don't know much about `resnet50`, but it's a residual network and that means that one of the earliest layers (usually the input) is feed back into the network in a later layer as a technique to increase accuracy on big networks (this one has ~150 layers).

More details: https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.03385

Comment: I kinda get an idea of what you mean and what happens. I cannot really understand how it incorporates both. Thank you very much for your answer :)